# Idle websocket connections dropping on AKS after exactly 2 minutes on browser

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, kubernetes, websocket, nginx-ingress

I'm working on transferring our platform from on-prem to AKS cluster. We have a websocket web application, that I have routed through Nginx load balancer ingress. The annotations used for the ingress are:

```
     kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
     kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
```

I can confirm that this translates to the following nginx configuration:

```
location ~* "^/<service-name>/(.*)" {

                        set $namespace      "<app-name>";
                        set $ingress_name   "<service-name>-ingress";
                        set $service_name   "<service-name>";
                        set $service_port   "6006";
                        set $location_path  "/<service-name>/(.*)";

                        rewrite_by_lua_block {
                                lua_ingress.rewrite({
                                        force_ssl_redirect = false,
                                        ssl_redirect = true,
                                        force_no_ssl_redirect = false,
                                        use_port_in_redirects = false,
                                })
                                balancer.rewrite()
                                plugins.run()
                        }

                        header_filter_by_lua_block {

                                plugins.run()
                        }
                        body_filter_by_lua_block {

                        }

                        log_by_lua_block {

                                balancer.log()

                                monitor.call()

                                plugins.run()
                        }

                        port_in_redirect off;

                        set $balancer_ewma_score -1;
                        set $proxy_upstream_name "<app-name>-<service-name>-6006";
                        set $proxy_host          $proxy_upstream_name;
                        set $pass_access_scheme  $scheme;
                        set $pass_server_port    $server_port;
                        set $best_http_host      $http_host;
                        set $pass_port           $pass_server_port;

                        set $proxy_alternative_upstream_name "";

                        client_max_body_size                    1m;

                        proxy_set_header Host                   $best_http_host;

                        # Pass the extracted client certificate to the backend

                        # Allow websocket connections
                        proxy_set_header                        Upgrade           $http_upgrade;

                        proxy_set_header                        Connection        $connection_upgrade;

                        proxy_set_header X-Request-ID           $req_id;
                        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP              $remote_addr;

                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $remote_addr;

                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host       $best_http_host;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port       $pass_port;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto      $pass_access_scheme;

                        proxy_set_header X-Scheme               $pass_access_scheme;

                        # Pass the original X-Forwarded-For
                        proxy_set_header X-Original-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;

                        # mitigate HTTPoxy Vulnerability
                        # https://www.nginx.com/blog/mitigating-the-httpoxy-vulnerability-with-nginx/
                        proxy_set_header Proxy                  "";

                        # Custom headers to proxied server

                        proxy_connect_timeout                   5s;
                        proxy_send_timeout                      3600s;
                        proxy_read_timeout                      3600s;

                        proxy_buffering                         off;
                        proxy_buffer_size                       4k;
                        proxy_buffers                           4 4k;

                        proxy_max_temp_file_size                1024m;

                        proxy_request_buffering                 on;
                        proxy_http_version                      1.1;

                        proxy_cookie_domain                     off;
                        proxy_cookie_path                       off;

                        # In case of errors try the next upstream server before returning an error
                        proxy_next_upstream                     error timeout;
                        proxy_next_upstream_timeout             0;
                        proxy_next_upstream_tries               3;

                        rewrite "(?i)/<service-name>/(.*)" /$1 break;
                        proxy_pass http://upstream_balancer;

                        proxy_redirect                          off;

                }
```

Here comes the weird bit. When I try to connect through the browser, it is able to find the service and create a websocket connection. However, after exactly 2 minutes (120 seconds) of inactivity, the connection drops.

I can also confirm that this only happens when the service is accessed through a browser (I'm using Chrome for testing). When I try to connect to the websocket using wscat via command line, the connection stays open for more than 10 minutes. I even tried to replicate the headers that chrome sends, but to no avail. The headers for the request made from browser are:

```
Host: <host>
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: <origin>
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
```

And nginx debug logs when the request is made, up until it disconnects are as follows:

```
2020/12/02 18:06:59 [debug] 102#102: *11638 http request line: "GET /<service-name>/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e HTTP/1.1"
2020/12/02 18:06:59 [debug] 102#102: *11638 http uri: "/<service-name>/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e"
2020/12/02 18:06:59 [debug] 102#102: *11638 test location: ~ "^/<service-name>/(.*)"
2020/12/02 18:06:59 [debug] 102#102: *11638 using configuration "^/<service-name>/(.*)"
2020/12/02 18:06:59 [debug] 102#102: *11638 http script value: "<service-name>-ingress"
2020/12/02 18:06:59 [debug] 102#102: *11638 http script value: "<service-name>"
2020/12/02 18:06:59 [debug] 102#102: *11638 http script value: "/<service-name>/(.*)"
2020/12/02 18:06:59 [debug] 102#102: *11638 http script value: "<app-name>-<service-name>-<port>"
2020/12/02 18:06:59 [debug] 102#102: *11638 http script var: "<app-name>-<service-name>-<port>"
2020/12/02 18:06:59 [debug] 102#102: *11638 http script regex: "(?i)/<service-name>/(.*)"
2020/12/02 18:06:59 [notice] 102#102: *11638 "(?i)/<service-name>/(.*)" matches "/<service-name>/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e", client: 10.216.148.206, server: <ingress-host>, request: "GET /<service-name>/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e HTTP/1.1", host: "<ingress-host>"
2020/12/02 18:06:59 [debug] 102#102: *11638 http script capture: "<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e"
2020/12/02 18:06:59 [notice] 102#102: *11638 rewritten data: "/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e", args: "", client: 10.216.148.206, server: <ingress-host>, request: "GET /<service-name>/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e HTTP/1.1", host: "<ingress-host>"
2020/12/02 18:06:59 [debug] 102#102: *11638 lua rewrite handler, uri:"/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e" c:1 "GET /<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e HTTP/1.1
2020/12/02 18:06:59 [debug] 102#102: *11638 http finalize request: -4, "/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e?" a:1, c:2
2020/12/02 18:06:59 [debug] 102#102: *11638 http run request: "/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e?"
2020/12/02 18:06:59 [debug] 102#102: *11638 http upstream check client, write event:1, "/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e"
2020/12/02 18:06:59 [debug] 102#102: *11638 http upstream request: "/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e?"
2020/12/02 18:06:59 [debug] 102#102: *11638 lua header filter for user lua code, uri "/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e"
2020/12/02 18:06:59 [debug] 102#102: *11638 lua capture header filter, uri "/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e"
Set-Cookie: INGRESSCOOKIE=1606932420.391.102.754662; Path=/<service-name>/(.*); Secure; HttpOnly
2020/12/02 18:06:59 [debug] 102#102: *11638 http output filter "/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e?"
2020/12/02 18:06:59 [debug] 102#102: *11638 http copy filter: "/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e?"
2020/12/02 18:06:59 [debug] 102#102: *11638 lua body filter for user lua code, uri "/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e"
2020/12/02 18:06:59 [debug] 102#102: *11638 lua capture body filter, uri "/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e" 2020/12/02 18:06:59 [debug] 102#102: *11638 http postpone filter "/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e?" 00007FFF78E0D8C0
2020/12/02 18:06:59 [debug] 102#102: *11638 http copy filter: 0 "/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e?"
2020/12/02 18:06:59 [debug] 102#102: *11638 http upstream request: "/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e?"
2020/12/02 18:06:59 [debug] 102#102: *11638 http upstream request: "/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e?"
2020/12/02 18:06:59 [debug] 102#102: *11638 http upstream request: "/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e?"
I1202 18:06:59.635816       7 socket.go:213] msg: [{"host":"<ingress-host>","method":"POST","requestLength":138,"status":"200","upstreamResponseLength":36,"upstreamLatency":0.004,"upstreamResponseTime":0.084,"path":"\/<service-name>\/(.*)","requestTime":0.081,"ingress":"<service-name>-ingress","namespace":"<app-name>","service":"<service-name>","responseLength":318}]
2020/12/02 18:07:06 [debug] 102#102: *11536 test location: ~ "^/<service-name>/(.*)"
2020/12/02 18:07:19 [debug] 102#102: *11536 test location: ~ "^/<service-name>/(.*)"
2020/12/02 18:09:00 [debug] 102#102: *11638 http run request: "/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e?"
2020/12/02 18:09:00 [debug] 102#102: *11638 http output filter "/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e?"
2020/12/02 18:09:00 [debug] 102#102: *11638 http copy filter: "/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e?"
2020/12/02 18:09:00 [debug] 102#102: *11638 lua body filter for user lua code, uri "/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e"
2020/12/02 18:09:00 [debug] 102#102: *11638 lua capture body filter, uri "/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e" 2020/12/02 18:09:00 [debug] 102#102: *11638 http postpone filter "/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e?" 00007FFF78E0D8B0
2020/12/02 18:09:00 [debug] 102#102: *11638 http copy filter: 0 "/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e?"
2020/12/02 18:09:00 [debug] 102#102: *11638 http finalize request: 0, "/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e?" a:1, c:1
2020/12/02 18:09:00 [debug] 102#102: *11638 lua log handler, uri:"/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e" c:0
10.216.148.206 - - [02/Dec/2020:18:09:00 +0000] "GET /<service-name>/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e HTTP/1.1" 101 97 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36" 583 121.143 [<app-name>-<service-name>-<port>] [] 10.251.137.49:4444 0 121.144 101 32aa8370ebd8b2c93f150f9fa6a45ebd
2020/12/02 18:09:00 [debug] 102#102: *11638 http script var: "/<service-name>/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e"
2020/12/02 18:09:00 [debug] 102#102: *11638 http map: "/<service-name>/<websocket-endpoint>/3eccfbdc-f066-4e4d-a635-d2933503a68e" "1"
I1202 18:09:00.707439       7 socket.go:213] msg: [{"host":"<ingress-host>","method":"GET","requestLength":583,"status":"101","upstreamResponseLength":0,"upstreamLatency":0,"upstreamResponseTime":121.144,"path":"\/<service-name>\/(.*)","requestTime":121.143,"ingress":"<service-name>-ingress","namespace":"<app-name>","service":"<service-name>","responseLength":443}]
```

This irks me because this wasn't a limitation on-prem. The only other difference between the two is that AKS connects over https (and wss), whereas on-prem, we used http (and ws) protocols. I want to understand why or what causes the connection to drop. I understand that it is probably best practice to drop connections that are idle for more than 2 minutes, and reconnect again, or implement an application level ping pong - however, I want to understand what's happening here and be able to explain why these changes are needed to the development team.

Been losing my head over this for the past couple of weeks. Any leads are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you use any cloud load balancer in front of the nginx?

Comment: @Jonas nothing in front of nginx, no.

Comment: Can you please the `nginx-ingress` service yaml? `kubectl get svc nginx-ingress-controller -o yaml` (of-course redact all private information, I just interested in the annotations). Thanks.

Comment: Are you using azure firewall ?

Comment: If you are using azure firewall, this may be similar to the watch problem in AKS cluster - watch is nothing but a websocket. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/troubleshooting#my-watch-is-stale-or-azure-ad-pod-identity-nmi-is-returning-status-500

Comment: quoting from the far page above : If you're using Azure Firewall like on this example, you may encounter this issue as the long lived TCP connections via firewall using Application Rules currently have a bug (to be resolved in Q1CY21) that causes the Go keepalives to be terminated on the firewall. Until this issue is resolved, you can mitigate by adding a Network rule (instead of application rule) to the AKS API server IP.